# Creating directories and files from TREE command output

Tags: bash, tree

I've used a tree command to list recursively about a hundred folders with some 150 files in them. This tree output is saved in a file.

How can I parse this file via bash and recreate these files and folders on a different computer?

Note that I don't need to copy these files. All I need is just the same naming convention on another computer where some custom work will be done.

Comment: `tree`'s output is for humans, not for programs; you should use something like `find` instead

Comment: How do you plan to recreate the files themselves? Simply as empty files?

Comment: @arnaud576875 i'd like to parse that output.

Comment: @Christian.K yes, those will be empty files. i don't need their content, just their names (which is a guid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

find will do what you want, something like

```
find /my/pathto/blah -type d | sed -e "s/^/mkdir -p /g" > commands
find /my/pathto/blah -type f | sed -e "s/^/touch /g" >> commands
```

The first find will create the instructions to make the directories.  The second find will create the instructions to create empty files.